# time measuring using clock() in n queen backtracking

Tags: c, time, n-queens, recursive-backtracking

After printing out the first solution it found, I'd like to print the amount of time taken finding the first solution as below.

Input N: 4

1 3 0 2

Time: 0.001sec

However, when I enter 30 as the input, it takes abnormally long as if it's in infinite loop. Moreover when I gave 31 as the input, it took me almost 15sec but the time printed out was only 0.002sec. I think I should change the positions of clock functions but since the code is exiting the program after printing out the first solution it became quite tricky for me to decide where to put them.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int put_queens(int column, int size, int* array);
int check_safe(int column, int row, int* array);
void print_sol(int size, int* array);

int main (void){
    int size, flag;
    int* array;
    clock_t t;
    printf("Input N: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    array = (int*) calloc(size, sizeof(int));

    t = clock();
    flag = put_queens(0,size, array);
    if(flag){
        printf("No solution");
        t = clock() - t;
        printf("\nTime: %.3fsec",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        free(array);
    }

    return 0;
}

int put_queens(int column, int size, int* array){
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    int row, flag;
    for( row = 0; row < size; row++ ){
        if( check_safe(column, row, array) ){
            array[column] = row;
            if(column == size - 1){
                print_sol(size, array);
                t = clock()-t;
                printf("\nTime: %.3fsec",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
                free(array);
                exit (0);
            }
            else{
                put_queens(column + 1, size, array);
            }
        }
    }
    if(row == size && column == size - 1){
        flag = 1;
    }
    return flag;
}

int check_safe(int column, int row, int* array){
    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < column; index++){
        if((array[index] == row ) || (abs(array[index]-row)==abs(column - index))){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void print_sol(int size, int* array){
    int column;
    for(column = 0; column < size; column++ ){
        printf("%3d", array[column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So input 4 is fast and input 30,31 very long.  How about 8,16, 24, etc?  Did `calloc(size, sizeof(int))` return `NULL`?

Comment: The function is recursive, so constantly calls clock().  You need to use clock() before you start recursing, so in main().  You already do this, you just forgot to report it.

Comment: Flag is never initialized.

Comment: @chux When I increased input , so did the time measured but only slightly: they were 0.002sec, 0.002sec, 0.003sec respectively. I just entered 35 as input and it is taking way to long again, but calloc did not return null.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below two condition and your for loop:

```
for( row = 0; row < size; row++ ){
    if( check_safe(column, row, array) ){
        array[column] = row;
        if(column == size - 1){
            print_sol(size, array);
            t = clock()-t;
            printf("\nTime: %.3fsec",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            free(array);
            exit (0);
        }
        else{
            put_queens(column + 1, size, array);
        }
    }
}
```

here in above when  first if condition satisfied only then it will check for second condition if (column == size -1). If first condition satisfied but ‘column’ value is already greater than ‘size’, second condition will never satisfy(for example column=31 and size = 30) for which recursion continue for ever  that is one of the reason for taking for a long time in some cases. Correct the second if condition to if(column > size). Also from a for loop you are calling the function recursively for which also it become more critical to satisfy the second if condition and recursion almost uncontrollable because for each recursion it has a for loop and that for loop call the method recursively again. Just imagine what is going on here. As there is a limit of recursion call the operating system kill the process abruptly for which you did not see any output of the program.   Regarding your  clock, please check whether it is getting the time properly or not with some print statement. Change the logic so that recursion should not continue for ever. Bye the way, what do you want to achieve here?